# CNRS postdoc research position in France - no mention of application procedure and one can apply just with CV and cover letter it seems (is it true?)

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, france

I'm looking at a few CNRS postdoc positions in France, and quite strangely I don't ever see any mention of application procedure. There's an 'apply' button where one can upload the CV and cover letter, but no place to ever upload recommendations. You can check this yourself by going to

https://emploi.cnrs.fr/RechercheAvancee.aspx

and do a quick search. But I'm picking some samples for you to see:

[image]

Here's another:

[image]

The only exception where they're asking for references is here (thankful to the person who pointed it out on this site:)
[image]

And after I click on 'apply', I go here: see here they're only requesting CV, cover letter and the project, that's all - no references!

[image]

Does this mean that the recommendations/referenced aren't necessary for the CNRS postdoc positions at all? It'd be really good to know!

What if one wants to supply some other documents to her/his candidature? How can (s)he upload them? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: I don't know about CNRS specifically, but recommendation letters are not a universal thing (luckily).

Comment: But under "Additional Information," they tell you where to send rec letters?

Comment: @gnometorule perhaps that should be an answer.

Comment: @gnometorule Yes they do and I was too late to notice that. But I assure you that it was not the case generally. Just go to https://emploi.cnrs.fr/RechercheAvancee.aspx and do a search and see for yourself that they're not asking for recommendations (which isn't a bad thing anyway), so I'm checking here. Modifying the question to avoid negative points now.

Comment: @Massimo Would you hire a postdoc without any recommendation letter (or other form of endorsement)?

Comment: @user151413 Yes, indeed. The selection should stand on itself. The problem of recommendation letters is that one's chance of being hired should not depend on someone else's capacity for writing recommendation letters. Indeed if a colleague of mine, someone I know personally, recommends someone, I'd happier, but it should not be fundamental.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano My point is not the *quality* of the letters, but their non-existence: If the PhD supervisor doesn't think their student deserves a letter, then this feels like a red flag. Badly written letters is a different story, that's not my point. But if a candidate is not able to provide any type of letter by their supervisor, would you hire them, unless everything else was stellar and/or you knew that their supervisor had a, let's say, difficult character?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to, add the reference names and contacts at the end of your CV, and state in the cover letter that reference letter can be provided or requested at the given referees.

I am not sure how is the "standard French CV", it may expected to have a reference section at the end, however you are applying in English so it is likely you have a lot of freedom in the formatting of your CV.

Final reccomnedation: contact the department secretary, human resources or even the responsible research person for further informations on choices that may affect your chances of getting a working position, not random stranger on the internet. Whatever information we provide you here, it is likely to be outdated as soon as CNRS changes its system.